# maven-resources-production:testing-service: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: sdk

I can’t start the service through idea, but the jar file is launched through the console.

I changed the SDK several times in the project settings. The problem is not heap, but something else.

Executing pre-compile tasks…
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Finished, saving caches…
maven-resources-production:testing-service: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Executing post-compile tasks…
Synchronizing output directories…